# Django response sometimes is blank

Tags: django-views

Here is the structure of my views.py:

```
def results(request):
    for x in 1-100:
        do 1/100th of the work
        open loading.html
        write to loading.html saying i've done x amount of work and force loading html to auto refresh.
        close loading.html

    render_to_response(results.html)

def loading(request):
    render_to_response(loading.html)
```

However once in a while (maybe once in every 20 refreshes) the webpage will display a completely blank page instead of the progress.